# Xamarin - How to pass variable to viewmodel

Tags: class, variables, xamarin

I have 2 Views. One has an event, that passes two variables to the second page and loads the page up:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (GalleryListEntry)e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Gallery(item.PhotographerCode, item.GalleryCode));
    }
```

in the second page I have this:

```
public Gallery(string photographerCode, string galleryCode)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The second page, has a Collection view that has its own Bindingsource.
For this bindingsource i have a Model, a Service, and a ViewModel. The service is called by the Viewmodel, and returns a List of images to be shown in the second page's collection view.

Inside this service class, I would need to access to the two variables passed above (`photograperCode`and `galleryCode`) but I cannot figure out how to pass the variables to the ViewModel so i can then forward it to the class.

ViewModel:

```
using GalShare.Model;
using GalShare.Service;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;

namespace GalShare.ViewModel
{
    class GalleryViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Gallery> Galleries { get; set; }
        public GalleryViewModel()
        {
        Galleries = new GalleryService().GetImageList();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried like this

```
        ((GalleryViewModel)this.BindingContext).pCode = photographerCode;
        ((GalleryViewModel)this.BindingContext).gCode = galleryCode;
```

but I get this error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` 
BindingContext is Null, but in the Xaml file i have this:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:GalleryViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine. First in your `Gallery`

```
public Gallery(string photographerCode, string galleryCode)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  BindingContext = new GalleryViewModel(photographerCode, galleryCode);
}
```

And now in the ViewModel

```
class GalleryViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Gallery> Galleries { get; set; }
  public GalleryViewModel(string pCode, string gCode)
  {
    this.pCode = pCode;
    this.gCode = gCode;
    Galleries = new GalleryService().GetImageList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i get an error in my gallery.xaml when i have the <vm:GalleryViewModel>. The error is this: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XLS0507 Type 'GalleryViewModel' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter. GalShare Gallery.xaml 10 
`

Comment: Delete that line you don't need it.

Comment: We already have binded the GalleryViewModel to your View in the code-behind